# Is the following correct concerning mathematical logic?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, soft-question

After having read initial chapters and solved questions from Prof. Tao's Real Analysis book, I decided to go through the appendix which explains Mathematical logic and proof writing because I was having issues with 'vacuously true if-then' type proofs.

Apologies beforehand for the diverse nature of the questions I have, stated below, but I will be grateful if I can get answers.

> 1. Am I right in saying that in statements like 'if A then B' there is no inherent meaning to the words 'if' and 'then' and the meaning of 'if A then B' is solely derived on the basis of how the truth values of 'if-then' statement are defined.

> 2. Consider the proposition, 'if x=2, then (x squared)=4'. Is my approach below of proving such statements right?

`Proof:`

`CASE 1 --- if x=2 is true, then 'if x=2, then (x squared)=4' can only be true if (x squared)=4 is true. The latter is true when x=2 is squared.`

`CASE 2 --- if x=2 is false, then 'if x=2, then (x squared)=4' is true by definition regardless of value of (x squared)`

`Hence, the proposition is true.`

Is this right? I am seemingly confused between what these statements mean in English and in Math.

> 3. Any recommendations on concise books on mathematical logic and proof writing for a beginner like myself, with more formalism and 'less English'?

Comment: You don't need that second case.  The only way $P \rightarrow Q$ can be false is if you are in the situation that $P$ is true and $Q$ is false.  You assumed $P$ to be true, then showed $Q$ is true.  All other cases are true by virtue of the fact that $P$ would be false.

Comment: As @J126 said, you can skip the second case, but your analysis of it is still correct. It's just that once you know that it goes that way, you can skip it in every other situation. Only the first case required you to care what the statements actually said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to answer your questions:

1. Words in general do not have inherent meaning. The english statement “if, then” when used mathematically is simply a way describing the logical implication. You are right that it simply corresponds to a truth table. However, it would benefit you to understand why it is that that phrase stands in for the logical implication.
2. That proof looks good. In the future, when proving an implication, you need not explicitly deal with the case where your hypothesis (left side) is false.
3. *Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning* by Eccles is a good book. I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not useful to think about truth values. What is really important is proving things. You just need to know that if you are requested to prove « if $A$ then $B$ », you can just prove $B$ and you are allowed to use $A$.

Proving statements is not asserting things are true: you can prove false things using false things.

You proof would be acceptable. Case 2 is useless. And I don’t like that you say « true » all the time.

My proof would be: we want to prove $x=2\Rightarrow x^2=4$. By the definition of the logical rules associated to $\Rightarrow$ (or « if… then… »), we can just assume $x=2$ and prove $x^2=4$. So, let us assume $x=2$ and prove $x^2=4$. We also assume $2^2 = 4$ (this assumption is usually allowed by teachers). Then $x^2=4$.

Comment: "I think it is not useful to think about truth values. What is really important is proving things." is meaningless. Like actually devoid of meaning. How can one possibly prove anything at all without thinking about truth values?

Comment: Well, when you study mathematical logic, you find out that defining truth is much more difficult than defining provability (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem, for example). You can, of course, when you start studying math, think that every well-formed sentence has a truth value; but it doesn't really add anything.